# how to parse a number like 5.1882449992845E+25 in php

Tags: php, parsing, number-formatting

I am working on this affiliate that computes numbers and adds them up then i get a number like 5.1882449992845E+25 how do i force the number to 2 decimal places so that i can have just integer.

I would like to know any php function that this with such numbers and what it means.

Comment: Unfortunately, the designers of PHP left out the capability of rounding numbers to a specified number of decimal places. I mean, if they hadn't, then clearly there would be some sort of documentation, right?

Comment: Q: Are you asking "How do I round the floating point number 5.18824..E+25 so that I get an integer?"  You can't *store* an integer that large on most PCs!

Answer (score 5):

Use number_format php function:

```
number_format(5.211545645612456,2);
```

For more information refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 1):

The number 5.1882449992845E+25 really means 5.1882449992845 * 10^25 ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)).

Unfortunately this is massive. If you are intent on storing this as a number (i.e. if you *need* to apply maths to it) then you should be able to parse the string and apply the exponent. Be warned however the max int size in PHP is usually 2 Billion (although this is platform independent). It's unlikely you'll be able to store this as an int. Otherwise if it is just to be used as an id or the like I would leave it as is or alternatively convert it to an int string.